# Having problems with internal classes when Mocking to a third party library using Moq

Tags: c#, mocking, moq, exchangewebservices

I'm trying to mock an method to a third-party library using moq.
The problem is that the method I'm mocking returns an object that is internal inside this framework, and thus I cannot instanciate this.

In the example below both the ChangeCollection and the ItemChange is internal, and I get the error: 'Cannot access internal constructor 'ChangeCollection' here'

I'm having problems figuring out a good solution for this, does someone have any ideas?

```
[TestMethod]
public void GetItemsForExistingEMails_should_call_GetItems_atleast_once()
{
    ewsMock = new Mock<IEwsIntegration>();
    ewsMock.Setup(e => e.GetItems()).Returns(new ChangeCollection<ItemChange>);
    var emailService = new EmailService(ewsMock.Object);

    var items = emailService.GetItemsForExistingEMails();

    ewsMock.Verify(e => e.GetItems(), Times.AtLeast(1));
    Assert.AreEqual(0, items.Count());
}

public interface IEwsIntegration
{
    ChangeCollection<ItemChange> GetItems();
}
```

Comment: Do you have access to the source of the 3rd party library ?

Comment: No it's the Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data lib

Comment: i dont understand how this library can have internal classes in its interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can get away with returning `IEnumerable<ChangeItem>` in your interface. It seems like [ChangeCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd633880%28v=exchg.80%29) is just an implementation of `IEnumerable<T>`.

```
public interface IEwsIntegration
{
    IEnumerable<ItemChange> GetItems();
}
```

Then you can simply return a list in your setup

```
ewsMock.Setup(e => e.GetItems()).Returns(new List<ItemChange>());
```

**Update:**

Since you have to use properties defined only on the concrete class, you have to create an adapter.

First create an interface with the members from the concrete class.

```
public interface IChangeCollection<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    bool MoreChangesAvailable { get; }
    string SyncState { get; }
}
```

Make sure you return this type from your interface:

```
public interface IEwsIntegration
{
    IChangeCollection<ItemChange> GetItems();
}
```

Then you have to create an implementation of `IChangeCollection<T>` which will simply direct calls to an instance of ChangeCollection.

```
public class ChangeCollectionAdapter<T> : IChangeCollection<T>
{
    private readonly ChangeCollection _changeCollection;

    public ChangeCollectionAdapter(ChangeCollection changeCollection)
    {
        _changeCollection = changeCollection;
    }

    public bool MoreChangesAvailable 
    { 
        get { return _changeCollection.MoreChangesAvailable; }
    }

    //other members
}
```

Comment: I need the members 'MoreChangesAvailable' and 'SyncState' on ChangeCollection :(

Comment: @TommyKey I totally missed them. I updated my answer with an adapter implementation.

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of possible options here.

**The first** requires you to have access to the 3rd party source to set up `InternalsVisibleTo`.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.aspx

This then allows you to have access to internal members on the dll you're referencing and looks something like this in the AssemblyInfo.cs:

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("Mynamespace.MyProject.Tests, PublicKey=00240...")]
```

**Secondly**, since `IEwsIntegration` is exposing types that are coming from a 3rd party application you could change that so you return your own types. This will give you better abstraction from the 3rd party app.

Here I'd use AutoMapper to manage the mapping between the return type of the 3rd party app and my own type. You can then mock out this dependency (I use an IAutoMapperWrapper) and have it return concrete implimentations of your return type in tests.

Even if you use your own custom converter you can mock out what it returns and provide some objects of your own type.

Comment: Thing is that the 3rd party lib is Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices I have thought of abstracting it but the ItemChange object have some methods I need for later.(load, delete etc.) I have a feeling that I might be over abstracting this.